# Power App - Dutch Number format and 2 Decimal Place check for Dutch or UK number formats

Tags: regex, powerbi, powerapps

I have a text box that in Holland will contain RENT Value of 12522,15 and in the UK version of the same Power App it will be 12522.15 . So I need a check on this text box to send out a warning message that the number if not in 2 decimal places . I cannot currently get the below formula to work with both scenarios . Any ideas ?

Psedu Code

If it is a Dutch number format , it will have a , in the number . Do the Dutch check to see if it is 2 dp then send out warning message.

If it is a UK number format , it will have a . in the number . Do the UK check to see if it is 2 dp then send out warning message .

On Select property of TEXT BOX

```
If ( IsMatch(DataCardValue11_3.Text, "\d+(\.)?") ,

If(!IsMatch(DataCardValue11_3.Text, Language(),"\d+(\,\d{0,2})?)?") ,Notify("Rental Value must be to 2 decimal places", NotificationType.Warning) ) ,

If ( IsMatch(DataCardValue11_3.Text, Language(), "\d+(\.)?") , If(!IsMatch(DataCardValue11_3.Text, Language(),"\d+(\.\d{0,2})?)?"),Notify("Rental Value must be to 2 decimal places", NotificationType.Warning) ) )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not single regex for both cases?

```
'^\d+[\.\,]\d\d$'
```

It'll only match when there's exactly 2 decimal places after `.` or `,`

Comment: Is my syntax right ? In Dutch Power App

If ( !IsMatch(DataCardValue11_3.Text; "^\d[\.\,]d{0,2})?" ) ; Notify("Rental Value must be to 2 decimal places";NotificationType.Warning) )

Comment: Got it working . Cheers 

If (
  !IsMatch(DataCardValue11_3.Text,"^\d+[\.\,]\d\d$")
   ,Notify("Rental Value must be to 2 decimal places" ,NotificationType.Warning )

 )